# C++ Access violation reading location when assigning pointer to a structure

Tags: c++

I need to write a tree, with nodes being strings (that is important, because I need some `string` class standard functions).

But when I try to implement my code, everything breaks on the earliest stage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct test {
    string str;
    struct test * r, * l;
};

int main() {    
    struct test* node = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    node->str = "abc";
    cout << node->str;
    return 0;
}
```

My Visual Studio throws `Access violation reading location` at me. What frustrates me more is that for `int` instead of `string` everything works just fine. So, I need just to be able to use `string` as a struct member, and to be able to code trees with that struct.

Comment: who told you / why do you think you can create a `std::string` in this way via `malloc` ? You can't.

Comment: simply do not use `malloc` in C++. There is no reason to do so (unless you really know what you are doing). If you read about usage of malloc, it was perhaps in a introduction to C.

Comment: `test node;` -> all problems gone

Comment: And why do you want/need to use `malloc`  instead of using `new test();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Looks like you are not learning c++ from a good source, your code is half "C" half bad C++. Learn cpp from : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: The other thing, C++ will NOT initialize variables, When using (member) pointers always make sure they are initialized. E.g `struct test { test* r{nullprt}; test* l{nullptr}; };` (r{} will also be fine)

Comment: About malloc, it will not result in constructors being called on structs/classes so in C++ always use `new` (or better std::make_unique to avoid memory leaks)

Comment: `malloc` is a C facility. It cannot construct C++ objects. it does not call constructors, it merely allocates memory. In C++ you can use `new` to allocate memory and construct objects, but in modern C++ calling raw `new` is rare. You'd use smart pointers for dynamic allocations